# Default dimension font size is small

Tags: autocad, autodesk

I have box with approximately dimensions 500mm x 500mm x 300mm. I would like to draw it's dimensions. When I draw dimensions line, default dimension text is very small.

[image]

And even not visible when I fit whole picture to screen:

[image]

Should I correct font size each time or I do something wrong? Where I can adjust dimension font size?

Answer (score 1):

You may change size of one dimension in properties (tab Fit , property: Dim scale overall)
[image]
Or better I think You should modify dimension style. Please check command `_dimstyle`